# Making a macro to use nbRoman in "text mode"

Tags: fonts, text, roman-numerals

The package `modroman` provides `\nbRoman` to typeset a number in roman numerals. In text mode, it works fine.

But in math mode, the font is rendered in italic, like a math symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modroman}

\begin{document}
$\nbRoman{3}$
\end{document}
```

while I'd prefer it to be rendered the same as in text mode (as an oxidation number). I know that I can enclose it in `\text{}`, but I'd like to write a single macro that would work and yield the same result in both modes. Like `\ensuremath` but in reverse.

The only thing I could think of is something like `\ensuremath{\text{\nbRoman{#1}}}` but it looks like an ugly hack when used in text mode, I don't like it. I usually use LuaLaTeX.

Comment: `\newcommand{myRoman}[1]{\textnormal{\nbRoman{#1}}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, and I really feel that I should know about `\textnormal`... If you could make your comment an answer, I'll validate it gladly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

```
\newcommand{\myRoman}[1]{\textup{\nbRoman{#1}}}
```

That version matches the weight of the surrounding text, and in particular gives you bold Roman numerals if you use it in a header.

If you want to copy the surrounding formatting in text mode, but not math mode, you can do this with:

```
\newcommand{\myRoman}[1]{\relax
  \ifmmode\textup{\nbRoman{#1}}%
  \else\nbRoman{#1}%
  \fi}
```

You probably don’t need that here, though, since you can just use `\nbRoman` in text mode and `\myRoman` in math mode.

Another solution, by @egreg in the comments, uses `\textnormal` rather than `\textup`.  That version will always typeset the symbol with the default weight and shape.  Some publishers, such as the AMS, recommend this for mathematical symbols in their house style.

Comment: I suggest to prepend `\relax` to `\ifmmode`. This will work better if `\myRoman` is used at the start of a tabular entry which changes the mode using the tabular template (e.g., with `>{$}c<{$}` and array.sty). This trick is widely used in the LaTeX kernel (e.g., in `\strut`, `\@nomath` and `\verb`); it works because `\relax` ends the search for `\noalign` and `\omit`, and causes TeX to insert tokens from the column template.

Comment: @frougon Like that?

Comment: Yes, but without the ugly percent after `\relax`. :-P Or you can put `\relax\ifmmode` stuck to each other, because it's sort of an idiom and the `\relax` is there to prevent the `\ifmmode` from being expanded too early (matter of taste). I can't upvote anymore, already done this morning! :)

Comment: @frougon Thanks for the suggestion!